# Использование PDO в Kohana Framework

Tags: pdo, php, kohana

Ничего не нагуглил, по этому поводу, а именно использование стандартных методов PDO и его возможностей в Kohana Framework. Может есть у кого инфа по этому вопросу?
ORM и прочее, использовать не хочется, даже если это удобною.

Comment: @Eugene Smiths, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: актуальная проблема

Answer (score 1):

А чем вам не нравится ORM или если не хотите юзать его то  можно спокойно использовать QueryBuilder для построения обычных запросов к БД.

Comment: @Viktor Sychenko, тем что драйвер БД и построитель запросов - это разные вещи, друг с другом напрямую не взаимодействующие.

Comment: @Fike, вы абсолютно правы